# C++ Static field access in the method

Tags: c++, static

How can I approach the months field in methods? The code in the constructor throws me an undefined reference to `CDate :: months'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```cpp
class CDate {
public:
  CDate(int year, int month, int day);
  static constexpr const int months[] = {0,  31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30,
                                         31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

private:
  int m_Year, m_Month, m_Day;
};

CDate::CDate(int year, int month, int day)
    : m_Year(year), m_Month(month), m_Day(day) {
  if (months[m_Month] != day)
    throw InvalidDateException();
}
```

Comment: Can you use C++17?  If so, just declare it `inline`.

Comment: `constexpr` implies `inline`. Also you don't need `const` when you use `constexpr`